# In Excel Spreadsheet (VBA) I need to search for a specific word in a column that is merged in some places and copy that ROW that is also merged

Tags: vba

I need to search for a specific word in a column that is merged in some places and if it exists, I need to copy that row that is also merged and paste it on a different sheet.
The below code I use copies and pastes ONLY the first merged Row that contains the word, then it gives me an error. It should go through the whole entire sheet and copy all the rows that contain this word.

I have commented on my code so its easier to follow.

```
Sub SearchForString()
    Dim LSearchRow As Integer
    Dim LCopyToRow As Integer

    On Error GoTo Err_Execute
    'Start search in row 10
    LSearchRow = 11
    'Start copying data to row 1 in Sheet12 (row counter variable)
    LCopyToRow = 1
    While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) <> Null
        'If value in column E = "ENGINE AUXILIARY PANEL (EAP 1)", copy entire row to Sheet12
        If Range("E" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "13.8kV SWITCHGEAR METERING CELL #A1 (+06)" Then
            'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
            Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
            Sheets("Sheet14").Select
            Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            'Move counter to next row
            LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1
            'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
            Sheets("Sheet11").Select
        End If
        LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1
    Wend
Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I cannot see why an error should be produced. However, you definitely should replace `<> Null` with `<> 0`, else you'll never enter the loop (as `Len` will always return a number and therefore never be NULL).

However, I think you can optimize your code significantly with another approach - simply use an Autofilter to filter for your search term and then copy all visible rows. Doing so (and using few other VBA shortcuts), I ended up with basically 4 instrcutions:

```
Sub nextVersion()
    Dim rngAll As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet11")
        Set rngAll = .Range("A1").Resize( _
            .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 5)
        rngAll.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
            "13.8kV SWITCHGEAR METERING CELL #A1 (+06)"
        If rngAll.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Columns.Count > 1 Then
            rngAll.Offset(1).Resize(rngAll.Rows.Count - 1). _
                SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
                Worksheets("Sheet14").Range("1:1")
        End If
        rngAll.AutoFilter
    End With
End Sub
```

**Update**
Given that you have merged cells in your data, the Autofilter solution won't work. This should do the job:

```
Sub CopyRows()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lngRows As Long
    Dim lngTargetRow As Long
    Dim lngRowsToCopy As Long

    Set rng = Sheet11.Range("E11")
    lngTargetRow = 0
    lngRows = Sheet11.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    Worksheets("Sheet14").UsedRange.Clear

    While rng.Row < lngRows
        lngRowsToCopy = rng.MergeArea.Rows.Count
        If rng.Value = "13.8kV SWITCHGEAR METERING CELL #A1 (+06)" Then
            rng.MergeArea.EntireRow.Copy _
                Worksheets("Sheet14").Range("A1").Resize(lngRowsToCopy).Offset(lngTargetRow).EntireRow
            lngTargetRow = lngTargetRow + lngRowsToCopy
        End If
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but when I use the above code I get Run-time error'1004' Cannot change part of a merged cell. How do I fix that?

Comment: Is there anything merged I column E?1

Comment: Yes column E is merged and column A is also merged with exactly the same amount of rows.

Comment: Merge across a row, eg A4:E4 or across a column, eg E4:E6? Can you unmerge?

Comment: Its merge across a column, example like A4:A6 are merged then I got like some data on CELLS (not merged) B4, B5, B6, C4, C5, C6, D4, D5, D6 and lastly Column E is merged E5:E6. And Im trying to copy all of ROWS 4,5 and 6. However, I cant unmerge.

Comment: under those circumstances, it is not possible to do the copying as far as I can see. this has nothing to do with autofilter or the macro - but you simply cannot copy only row 6 for example if it contains a merged cell A4:A6! I'd recommend to unmerge the cells in A and E - and simply fill the blanks with the content from the cell above! this can be done with very small effort (select A & E, goto (ctrl-g)->special->blank, enter `=A1` where A1 is the cell above the currently active cell, press Ctrl-Enter - done!)

Comment: Thank you but I am not trying to copy only Row 6. I want to copy all the rows (that contains the phrase Im searching for in column E) if there exists merged cells and also contains the phrase in column E I want to copy those rows even if they are merged.

Comment: To be clear, column A, E and all the other columns if any are merged they are merged with the same number of rows. So column A usually is merged and its is merged with the same amount of rows as the other columns if they are merged and the ones that are not merged contain data that I also want to copy.

Comment: Can you please give me your email or something? I can send my Spreadsheet to you, because I know once you look at it I know you will understand me and be able fix it.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to highlight the rows that are copied from the sheet and to also search for the phrase "13.8kV SWITCHGEAR METERING CELL #A1 (+06)" in column E and H not just E but every time I change it the code does not work.

Answer (score -1):

```
{
Sub FindTheFeret()
With Worksheets(1).Cells
Set c = .Find("Feret", LookIn:=xlValues)
i = 1
If Not c Is Nothing Then
    firstAddress = c.Address
    Do
        c.EntireRow.Copy
        Worksheets(2).Rows(i).EntireRow.PasteSpecial
        i = i + 1
        Set c = .FindNext(c)
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
End If
End With
End Sub
}
```